# Installing Stanford Parser's Python interface: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 rake aborted

Tags: python, installation, stanford-nlp, jpype

I'd like to install the stanford parser's python interface.

http://projects.csail.mit.edu/spatial/Stanford_Parser

When running **rake setup** to install jpype first, I keep ge

```
In file included from src/native/common/jp_reference.cpp:1:0:
src/native/common/include/jpype.h:45:17: schwerwiegender Fehler: jni.h: Datei oder     Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Kompilierung beendet.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
rake aborted!
```

The error message is english-german-mixed.  It says: heavy failure: jni.h: File or directory not found.

When I try to install the stanford-parser itself, the same thing happens.

Yes, I python-dev is already installed on my system.
I'm working on Ubuntu and with python2.7.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages says you are missing `jni.h`.
You can use the search tool at http://packages.ubuntu.com to find which package provides the missing file:

For the most recent version of Ubuntu, Quantal (12.10), these packages provide the jni.h:

```
File    Packages
/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8.0/include/jni.h    gcc-snapshot
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include/jni.h   gcj-4.6-jdk
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/include/jni.h   gcj-4.7-jdk
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6/include/jni.h   gcj-4.6-jdk
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.7/include/jni.h   gcj-4.7-jdk
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-snap/include/jni.h  gcc-snapshot
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/include/jni.h  openjdk-6-jdk
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include/jni.h  openjdk-7-jdk
```

Either openjdk or gcj will do; [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/what-is-debians-stance-regarding-gcj-and-openjdk) may help clarify the difference.

Comment: hmm... ok. I'm working on 64 bit, maybe I should have mentioned that. But the file seems to be in openjdk-7-jdk for amd64, too. And I have it installed. So why does this error message appear?

Comment: thanks, I installed gcj and gcc-snapshot and now the error message changed

Comment: Sorry; from the error message you posted, I don't know the next step. It may help if you update your post with the full output, or at least more of it. It may provide a clue someone will recognize.

Answer (score 1):

jni.h is the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) header, so you will need to make sure you have Java installed. For Ubuntu there is a `openjdk-6-jdk` package which I've confirmed has the require file available.

Comment: I have openjdk-7-jdk. Shouldn't that be sufficant?

Comment: @Sadik What's the output of `dpkg-query -L openjdk-7-jdk | grep "jni.h"` ?

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/jni.h

But I just noticed, that on trying to install, the error message changed (I installed two other packages in which jni.h is included: gcc-snapshot and gcj-4.6-jdk). The error message now says: 
**error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [cd JPype-0.5.4.1 && python setup.py build...]**